# RxAndroidBle losing connection when Garmin watch is connected to phone

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I have an app that uses RxAndroidBle and communicates with a RN4871 module using GATT.

I also have a Vivoactive 4 smartwatch from Garmin for personal use.

When my phone is connected to the watch, the app that I am working on and uses RxAndoidBle has a very hard time to connect, and after several connections I need to restart the Bluethoot of the phone to be able to connect again. Restarting the RN4871 module has no effect on the problem, thus I know the problem is in the Android.

When connecting I get the following error:

onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=8 device=XX:XX:XX:XX:CA:00
2023-12-21 04:30:58.498 20749-21167 BluetoothC...nViewModel com.kostov.canthrust                 E  connectToDevice: error while connecting to device
com.polidea.rxandroidble3.exceptions.BleDisconnectedException: Disconnected from MAC='XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' with status 8 (GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION or GATT_CONN_TIMEOUT)

Any ideas on the root cause will be very helpful, as asking anyone who buys the product to not use a Garmin watch is not a great strategy.

I tried to reset the BluetoothGatt before connecting, also I tried to disconnect the BluetoothGatt after disconnecting. Same results.

Comment: Hello, a couple of questions:
1. what FW your RN4871 uses?
2. what phone are you testing with?
3. does the same phone work when your Vivoactive 4 smartwatch is turned off?
4. under what circumstances you achieved a successful connection?

Comment: Hi, thank you for asking. 1. The module FW is 1.18. 2. Phone is Samsung S22 Ultra 3. Yes it connects with no problems when the vivoactive is not connected 4. When the vivoactive is off or if I restart the Bluetooth of the phone and connect in the first few seconds to the module.

Comment: From what I see on [this site](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/RN4871) you may want to check FW 1.42 which is the newest as it seems to fix some issues — maybe It will fix yours?

Comment: Will do. I need some hardware changes as the module is already installed on the device. But I will do then and report what is the result with the newest firmware. Another thing I am planning to test is to setup an ESP32-C3 module to behave as the RN4871 and see if it will have the same issues.

Comment: So I recreated the service of the RN4871 using an ESP32-C3 module. When the same app and phone connect to the ESP everything is OK regardless of the connection to the Vivoactive 4. So for now I think I have proven that the RN4871 has some problem in FW 1.18. In the coming days I will test with the latest firmware and post the results here.

Comment: Did you got a chance to check the latest firmware?

Comment: Not yet, I have the hardware now, I will test it in the coming weeks